# javascript, just like stackoverflow's comment preview

Tags: javascript

I need to do a preview just like how stackoverflow does their preview such as when you write questions or add comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**I created this for you as demo.**](http://jsbin.com/eraca) You can expand on that, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an idea.

You can do that by wiring up a onchange event on the textarea in which you are typing and in the function that handles the onchange event update a div with the text from the textarea and that div is shown below which serves as a preview.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case your interested in the markup language ([Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)) too, *plus* the preview system, check out the live preview demos of

- [Showdown](http://attacklab.net/showdown/)
- [WMD Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/demo)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **[WYSIWYM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM)** editor for this.

**[WMD: The Wysiwym Markdown Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/)**